# iOS Facebook SDK,how to login within App , not in safari

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use the Facebook iOS SDK to authenticate within an app (not go to Safari), and also keep those authentication credentials for the next launch of the app?

I have used`Facebook SDK` sample code `SessionLoginSample` to check . It opens the Facebook login account in the safari....I want it to open with-in the app ..

I am not using `FBConnect` as it is been expired ...How to use it for the  `Facebook SDK`

of 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk ...its  sample code

`https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample`

[this sample code here~~](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample)

Comment: Did you install the Facebook APK on your device?

Comment: Facebook APK ?? whats that?? i Have installed Facebook SDK and it works fine for the safari opening

Comment: Sorry, was thinking Android there...

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook iOS SDK will open within the app provided your user is on iOS 6 and has their Facebook account setup within the device. Otherwise, it will gracefully fallback to the Facebook App (if installed) and then only to Safari. From the [SDK Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/):

> The native Login Dialog is available after a user has logged into
>   Facebook on their device. If the device isn't connected to Facebook,
>   the native Login Dialog isn't available and permission requests will
>   be made via the fast-app-switch to the Facebook app (if installed) or
>   Safari. The Facebook SDK methods [...] will seamlessly fallback to
>   this fast-app-switch behavior.

If your user has neither Facebook configured on their iOS 6 device nor the Facebook app installed and you still want the login to happen within your app, your best alternative might be to pull up a UIWebView pointed to your own server somewhere that carries out a [server-side login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/).

Bear in mind a big disadvantage of a UIWebView-based approach is that your UIWebView does not share cookies with Safari so even if the user is already logged in within Safari they'll still need to re-enter their username and password again in your app. I'd be a little hesitant to do so in a third party app since there's no way to know if they're spoofing the Facebook site and phishing for my credentials.

Comment: ya but if u try this sample code https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SwitchUserSample of Facebook sdk for iOS 5 ...it opens the login within app for next users.. but problem is I don't know how to implement this...I want the same in the `SessionLoginSample` sample code ....

Comment: I want Facebook code to use in my app to login from 
FB but want to open login page not in safari thats y i was looking for `SessionLoginSample

Comment: hey can u check this one?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354191/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-8-crash-xcode-on-alternative-login

Answer (score 0):

FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;